# Class inheritance, code factorisation, php object model

Tags: php, inheritance, object

Say I have an abstract class Entity, I also have a handful of abstract classes Provider, Model, Service,... all extending directly Entity. Finally, i have a last set of concrete classes ConcreteProvider, ConcreteModel, ... that extends respectively Provider, Model, ...

On each instance of Concrete* I want a method getId() that when called on an instance of a class which extends Provider ( like ConcreteProvider ), it returns the string 'Provider', and so on for Model and ...

The only way I found to achieve that is :

```
abstract class Entity {
    abstract function getId ();
}

abstract class Provider extends Entity {
    function getId () {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

abstract class Model extends Entity {
    function getId () {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

class ConcreteProvider extends Provider {
}

class ConcreteModel extends Model {
}

$cp = new ConcreteProvider();
echo $cp->getId() . "\n"; // returns the string Provider
$cm = new ConcreteModel();
echo $cm->getId(); // returns the string Model
```

Code duplication is here obvious. I'm looking for the same behaviour without duplicate. I guess it would be nice to put the method into Entity.

Have you an idea ? How would you do that ?

// Edit

Of course, there is a way to move getId into Entity :

```
abstract class Entity {
    function getId () {
      $class = get_called_class();
      while ( __CLASS__ !== get_parent_class($class) )
        $class = get_parent_class($class);
      return $class;
    }
}
```

But there is a lot of computation for, imo, nothing worth...

Comment: is this level of code duplication unacceptable? You need some specialisation here to make the distinction between `Model` and `Provider`.

Comment: If there's no other way, it'll be acceptable, for sure.

Comment: I think your additional code in your edit sacrafices code intent and adds more code than your original duplication. It also makes your code PHP 5.3+ which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: this is not an issue, moreover here i presented only two classes that duplicate the said code, irl there are 10+...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best I found, using my second proposition, and adding to it memoization.

```
abstract class Entity {
    private $subType = '';
    function getId () {
      if ( $this->subtype )
        return $this->subType;
      $class = get_called_class();
      while ( __CLASS__ !== get_parent_class($class) )
        $class = get_parent_class($class);
      return $this->subType = $class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of magic, thus I recommend the straight-forward way

```
const ID = 'Provider';
public function getId () {
    return self::ID;
}
```

Or just

```
function getId () {
    return 'Provider';
}
```

but with the constant its easier to compare

```
$x->getId() == Provider::ID;
```

Comment: I understand the point, but my goal is not to bother with maintaining one more value by hand...

Comment: I see just two values and worth to say: Beware of too much magic. Apart from that its of course something you must decide yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2014:**

If you are running PHP 5.4+ you could use a [trait](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to share this function between Models and Providers.

---

What is to stop you from using the type system? Where you might currently call:

```
if ($object->getId() == 'Provider') {
    // provider specific code
}
```

Can't you use:

```
if ($object instanceof Provider) {
    // provider specific code
}
```

Admittedly using type conditionals like this defeats the purpose of polymorphism. I might be able to offer better advice with more context.

Comment: Good point, but the code presented here is the root of my trouble, in fact getId is expected to return a string identifier. So there are no case where I do what you wrote, ony things like $id = $cp->getId();

Comment: @dader Then I would go with the solution in your question and follow the Three Strikes and Refactor rule: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStrikesAndYouRefactor

Comment: haha, thanks for the link. But I think it's just something you cannot achieve otherways.

Comment: Well it's good enough for Martin Fowler http://stackoverflow.com/a/2298357/122075

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Entity {
  public static function getId() {
    return get_called_class();
  }
}


class Model extends Entity {

}

class Provider extends Entity {

}

$a = new Model();
echo $a->getId(); //returns Model

$b = new Provider();
echo $b->getId(); //returns Provider

$c = new Entity();
echo $c->getId(); //returns Entity
```

Using late static binding. Your php version should be greater than 5.3.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Comment: If he subclasses `Model` this method will defeat his inheritance chain and return the subclass name?

Comment: it does not work, using late static binding leads to return the actually called class, so with ConcreteProvider, it will return ConcreteProvider, not provider

Comment: Even though this solution didn't out-right prove to be the solution, kudos for suggesting LSB.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PHP magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) __toString() for the classes you want to get class names for, then when you typecast the object as a string, it will return the class name:

```
abstract class Provider extends Entity {
    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

abstract class Model extends Entity {
    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

$cp = new ConcreteProvider();

var_dump($cp); // Outputs object

// Force cast of $cp object to a string, which calls __toString()
var_dump((string) $cp); // Outputs Provider

// Vanilla echo forces object cast to string
echo $cp; //Outputs Provider

$cm = new ConcreteModel();

var_dump($cm); // Outputs object

// Force cast of $cp object to a string, which calls __toString()
var_dump((string) $cm); // Outputs Model

// Vanilla echo forces object cast to string
echo $cm;
```

With this approach you don't need to force a `getId` method upon child classes extending the parent `Entity` class.

Also, Using a `getId()` for this functionality is mis-leading imo, 99% of the time when I call on a classe's `getId()` method, I expect an int representing a specific instance of an object, fetched from a store (database, cache, flat-file).

Comment: In fact, there is a method __toString in entity which one call getId ;)

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow you. If there is more code, please update your OP.